# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `moment` imported from `ui/routes/application`

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I'm trying to upgrade moment from 2.18.0 to 2.29.4 along with ember. I have upgraded ember to 4.12.2 but when I run the application, I'm getting Uncaught Error: Could not find module `moment` imported from `ui/routes/application`

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `moment` imported from `ui/routes/application`
    at vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:1:1279
    at l (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:1:1344)
    at a.findDeps (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:1:3101)
    at l (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:1:1400)
    at requireModule (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:1:631)
    at e.value (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:98:414364)
    at r.value (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:98:420375)
    at r.value (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:98:416269)
    at r.value (vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:98:416806)
    at vendor.js?v=49fe7d16-7e19-4c82-a90f-54e1de235b76:22:6478
```

Comment: is moment in your package.json? are you using ember-moment?

Comment: Yes moment is in package.json and ember-moment also add as dev dependency

Comment: What version of ember-moment and ember-source do you have? on the README here: https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-moment, there are a bunch of instructions, which should help? I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ember-moment@10` (or higher), the [README](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-moment#using-momentjs-in-ember-apps--addons) provides these instructions:

> This addon provides Ember-specific Helpers and a Service that make it convenient to use Moment.js in your templates. If you just want to call Moment.js directly from Javascript, you don't need this addon.
>
> The recommended way to use Moment.js in an Ember **app** is:
>
> 1. Add *either* `moment` or `moment-timezone` to your dependencies.
> 2. Make sure you have `ember-auto-import` in your dependencies.
> 3. Make sure you *don't* have `ember-cli-moment-shim` in your dependencies (it would add a redundant copy).
> 4. Use imports in your Javascript like `import moment from 'moment'` or `import moment from 'moment-timezone'`.
> 5. *Optional but strongly recommended*: Configure which locales and timezones will be included in your app by following the instructions below in "Controlling Locale and Timezone Data".

So, working through the check-list, are all the steps / criteria / setup met?

Comment: Yes i followed all the steps mentioned in the README and did the setup

Comment: the above steps are known to work, so something else may be at play. can you provide a reproduction of your issue on GitHub? thanks!

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/embroider-build/ember-auto-import/issues/578#issuecomment-1532096597